# Desktop app. communicate with remote Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, client-server

I am looking for some code examples of a local java program that communicates with a servlet on a tomcat server.

I am trying to write a program that can send a single string to the server and be returned another string. Quite a simple thing but cannot find any tutorials or examples for communication with a remote server.

Comment: Did you put some thought/research into your choice of using servlets?  Is all communication going to be done from Java on the client side?  If so, HTTP+Servlets might be a useless layer over simply using sockets wrapped in a Writer/Reader.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I need the client program to run outside of a browser if that what your getting at. Do you have any examples of sockets using Writer/Reader?

Comment: What is your question?  (No - adding question marks to statements does not make them questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple google

http://www.frank-buss.de/echoservlet/index.html

alternatively the sun server/client example tutorial is here.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I've been using that exact tutorial, although the client is on the server, I'd like to see an example that connects to the servlet remotely.

Comment: ahh so you mean like a desktop application?

Comment: Yeah I guess I do, something that you can just fire up and it will communicate with the server over the network/internet.

Comment: @eric-banderhide please try the sun tutorial, I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, with that tutorial, say my tomcat server is addressed at http://foobar.com on port 8080

Then I put that tutorial in http://foobar.com/dir1/dir2 

Do I set the host name as http://foobar.com/dir1/dir2?

Comment: @EricBanderhide You dont have to set your hostname, try localhost or 127.0.0.1 and follow the instructions from the tutorial